# Iterate through all elements on a div and click on each on Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to get the data inside of every page from a list and would like help to iterate through all the elements with Puppeteer.

I'm accessing an element with the following code:

```
await page.waitForSelector('#element')
      .then(() => console.log("got it"))
      .catch(e => {
        console.log("Error: " + e);
      });
```

This `#element` is populated with a `span` that has around 20 div (child) with a clsas of `.li` like below:

```
<div id="element">

    <div id="other">
    </div>

    <span id="listofitemstoclick">

        <div class="li">

        </div>

            <div class="li">
            
            </div>

                <div class="li">
            
                </div>
                      ...
    </span>
</div>
```

I need to click on the first, go back, click on the second, and so on.

Any approach that would be good here?

As the `.li` doesn't have any `href`, I believe I need to get each child and click one by one, but yet couldn't find any good way to retrieve each child, click, go back and click on the next.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Are you sure that is how the HTML looks because it is invalid ? IDs are supposed to be unique.

Comment: @Titus hey thanks for the answer. I made a mistake there. I've corrected the question. They are all css classes.

Comment: Why are you chaining a `then` onto the `waitForSelector`? `await` will give you undefined. I don't see any code to select or click these `li`s. It'd help to see the live page and a [mcve] of what you're doing with it. Thanks.